# Uploading flash flipbook to mu wordpress site

Tags: uploads, flash

I have to upload a flash flipbook (swf file) on my wordpress site. The problem is that the flipbook generated has two subfolders along with the book.swf.. So what I need to uplaod to media is

- book.swf
- framework.swf
- js

  - some files
- img

  - page00
  - page01
  - page...
  - page205

I tried the AddFromServer plugin but nothing works for subfolders.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Upload your files over FTP to some dedicated location, like `wp-content/flashbook/` or `wp-content/uploads/flashbook/`, and manually include the markup in your page. Presumably, the Flash only runs on one page so this shouldn't be too cumbersome.

Actually embedding Flash isn't as simple as linking to it, but [there is plenty of information on the web](http://animation.about.com/od/flashanimationtutorials/qt/embedswfwebpage.htm).

This is going to be very difficult to manage otherwise. WordPress doesn't know what to do with "groups" of media like that. It would take a fair chunk of complicated code to make it work and I don't see the benefit.

Comment: So I just write [swf file="flashbook/mybook.swf"] ?

Comment: ^^ Only if you have a shortcode that handles the markup, and you didn't mention one.

Comment: :) yeah, that probably sounded silly... but relative urls don't work and (since I'm using Gandi.net's SimpleInstance) I don't have the complete url

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to say about whatever restrictions your host puts on things but how can you not have the complete URL?

Comment: No clue.. I got the complete URL but it asks for my admin login (server login) to view the files..

Comment: You are dealing with some kind of server specific security issue. Talk to your host.